# VB.NET get related data while entering input in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have two textboxes, one is for the ProductName and the 2nd is for ProductPrice.

I am not able to get the `txtProductPrice` value from the database while entering the `txtProductname`. Please help me

Here is the code I am trying to execute...

```
Try
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE name = '" & txtPN.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then

        'what will i do here???

    End If
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You are executing it in a Thread on KeyPress event or on TextChanged event? If so, you should probably check if `InvokeRequired` is set on the TextBox that you wish to set, and if necessary return to ui thread to set the textbox. I might also suggest to either limit the items you get return (TOP 1 or limit 0, 1, don't know which sql it is from the statement) so you could show only 1 result, maybe event `like`instead of `=` name to make it more accurate when more and more text is entered (don't forget to set it to empty or 0 in case no results are found.

Comment: i am doing this in tabindexchanged

Comment: `what will i do here???` how can we answer that?  It is your app, your UI; we have no idea what the data is or what you want to do with it.

Comment: After the ExecuteReader method is called, "dr" is now an SqlDataReader object. So to get the values, you need to access the "item" property of the "dr" object.